# Regarding the size limitaion of application in phonegap build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-pushplugin

hiii 
I am new to phonegap build.I have been trying to upload a file of size 20Mb,but its saying that the file is too large.Can anyone give an idea that what will be the size limit of the application for paid and free service.
Please Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **15Mb** with *free* subscription,
and **40Mb** with the *paid* at the moment

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2014 this is updated:

> The new limits are 50MB for free tier users, 100MB for standalone users and 1GB for Creative Cloud subscribers.

http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/12/09/phonegap-build-new-features/